# How to get the Last Element from the View Port in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I need to get the last product from a view port with a list of products in infinite scroll. How to get the last element (Last li tag) in the view port using jquery?

Comment: try $('li').last();

Comment: @RohitVerma You've missed the essential _"from the view port"_ part.

Comment: Yes i want the last element from the view port.... How to get it?

Comment: @Andreas I need the last element from the view port.... The link provided checks if an element is visible or not. Can anyone explain how to get the last element from view port?

Comment: Get all `<li>` elements, find the first non-visible, grab the previous `<li>` - done.

Comment: @Andreas. Thank you..!! Will try it.